# Create Menu starting from page uID

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I have the necessity to create a HMENU that start from a certain page uid and go recursively along all pages under that one. i tryed to start with a 'special'  menu 'list' with that page as the only listed, but dosn't work.
Is this possible? any Idea?

Thank in advance for any suggestion

EDIT:
That's the solution that work form me

```
lib.footmenu >
lib.footmenu = HMENU
lib.footmenu.special = directory
lib.footmenu.special.value = 132
lib.footmenu.excludeUidList = 287
lib.footmenu {
    1= TMENU
    1.expAll= 1
    1.wrap = <ul class="menufoot1">|</ul>

    1.NO{
        wrapItemAndSub = <li class="level1">|</li>
        1.ATagTitle.field = title
        1.ATagParams =
    }

    2 < .1
    2.wrap = <ul class="menufoot2">|</ul>

    3 < .2
    3.wrap = <ul class="menufoot3">|</ul>

    4 < .3
    4.wrap = <ul class="menufoot3">|</ul>

    5 < .4
    5.wrap = <ul class="menufoot3">|</ul>

    6 < .5
    6.wrap = <ul class="menufoot3">|</ul>


}
```

Now i have one more problem. i want to exclude all page under a certain uid (it's the event page that have too many page inside). I tried with `excludeUidList` but obviusly it ignore also the page metioned(uid=287), but i want to ignore only its childrens.

Comment: please, write more information in your question, like for example what goes wrong and share your TypoScript code.

Comment: Yes, sorry my fault. I added it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go for

```
special = directory
```

and you should add

```
expAll = 1
```

to the first level of TMENU (which is then copied over to your sublevels).

Read more about the special keyword in TMENU:
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/ContentObjects/Hmenu/Index.html#the-special-property

Comment: any idea for exlude all page children of a determined one?

Comment: For sure. excludeUidList may be your friend.
Subpages of excluded pages won't show either.
You could also exclude doktypes with excludeDoktypes
More to read: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/ContentObjects/Hmenu/Index.html

Comment: but excludeUidList exlude also thet arent page. as example, if i wnat to ignore page 287 children, whit excludeUidList=287 i'll ignore all it subpages, but i'll go to ignore also the page 287

Comment: That's correct.
I see four different solutions:
1. Add the children of that page to the excluidUidList.
2. Go for an if-clause and remove sublevels for your parent id.
3. do something fancy with javascript, or better: pure css.
4. use a different doktype for that children to be excluded.

But please note: this is totally out of scope of the original question. Please add a new question to stackoverflow if you need more help.

Comment: There's a fifth possible solution: maxItems / minItems.
[for sure, there are more solutions, but this is out of scope, as told aready ...]
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/ContentObjects/Hmenu/Index.html#hmenu

Answer (score 1):

You just have to add more levels within your TMENU definition.

See property "1/2/3" in the docs: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/ContentObjects/Hmenu/Index.html

If you want to see more levels at once you should use the expAll property: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/MenuObjects/Tmenu/Index.html

Comment: i know that properties, and used it. But it doesn't work. I added my typoscript code

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem here, as correctly pointed by @BastianBalthasarBux is the lack of `expAll = 1`

I think that your TypoScript code could be simplified in this way: (I used [this one](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-typoscript-in-45-minutes/master/en-us/CreateAMenu/Index.html) as example):

```
lib.footmenu > 
lib.footmenu = HMENU
lib.footmenu.special = list
lib.footmenu.special.value = 132

lib.footmenu {
  1 = TMENU
  1.expAll = 1 
  1.wrap = <ul class="menufoot1">|</ul>
  1.NO {
    wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li> 
    ATagTitle.field = title
    ATagParams =
  } 
  2 < .1
  2.wrap = <ul class="menufoot2">|</ul>

  3 < .1
  3.wrap = <ul class="menufoot3">|</ul>
}
```